# SQL rate (percentage) calculation - division by zero error

Tags: sql, postgresql, rate

Tried to user NULLIF or IFNULL functions but still receiving division by zero message.

```
SELECT 
client_id
,COUNT(distinct CASE WHEN status = 'failed' THEN id END) AS count_FAILS
,COUNT(distinct CASE WHEN status = 'completed' THEN id END) AS count_COMPLETED
,COUNT(distinct CASE WHEN status IN ('failed') THEN id END)
 /CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'completed' THEN id END) AS FLOAT) 

FROM journey
GROUP BY 1
```

Example database and query
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=efc0cd25843e852ab7a3aa8fe49e6986

Is distinct necessary for such queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
COUNT(distinct CASE WHEN status IN ('failed') THEN id END) * 1.0 /
NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'completed' THEN id END), 0)
```

You can cast to a float.  I prefer to just use `* 1.0`.

I note that the definition of `count_completed` uses `count(distinct)`, but this ratio does not.  That is perhaps a bug.

I would be more likely to want the *proportion* of failed statuses overall, rather than the ratio.  If that is acceptable and the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is not necessary for either count, then this can be simplified to:

```
avg( (status = 'failed')::int )
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a quick way to substitute value = 1 instead of 0 to receive rate, not the empty cell?

Comment: @snowboi . . . If I understand your comment, you can use `coalesce(<expression>, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NULLIF`:

```
,COUNT(distinct CASE WHEN status IN ('failed') THEN id END)/
 NULLIF(CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'completed' THEN id END) AS FLOAT),0)
```

**[DBFidde Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2bf1776b8849875407efb06359257a9a)**

---

I would rewrite entire query as:

```
SELECT 
  client_id
  ,COUNT(distinct id) FILTER(WHERE status = 'failed') AS count_FAILS
  ,COUNT(distinct id) FILTER(WHERE status = 'completed') AS count_COMPLETED
  ,COUNT(distinct id) FILTER(WHERE status = 'failed')
   /NULLIF(1.0 * COUNT(distinct id) FILTER(WHERE status = 'completed'),0)
FROM journey
GROUP BY client_id;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d6503d5de569ccd8ffc11fd3701c03e1)**

Comment: Thanks, Lukasz! what's the difference between Demo and Demo2? I can't see any

Comment: @snowboi Explicit `GROUP BY client_id` instead of 1 and using  `COUNT(distinct id) FILTER(WHERE status = 'failed')` instead of `CASE`

Comment: I meant that can't spot the difference in the results. Is this method faster for large dataset or so? I think there is no difference whether you use 1 or client_id in GROUP BY statement

Comment: @snowboi If you don't bother about positional syntax then no. `ORDER BY 1/GROUP BY 1` may be treated as anti-pattern - matter of taste